# C# code or library to Update virtual directory contents without breaking clients

Tags: c#, iis, web

I have a lot of regularly updating static content that is made available via HTTP through IIS as a Virtual Directory. I have a C# application that updates this static content. The static content represents a matching set.
This content changes regularly and is validated before being made available to clients.  I am currently doing a Directory Copy using [this code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but it is a bit brute force.

The content has a manifest file with version information. I know I can update the manifest file last but I don't want to pull the rug from under clients that are already downloading older content and leave them with a dirty set of files.

What is the recommended way to do a folder replace so that existing clients don't get a mixed up version of the file set? This must be common but I cannot find any libraries or best practice guidance to do this.
I've looked things like rsync for Windows and other backup/restore style tools but they all seem like overkill and generally don't have an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [Microsoft Sync Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/sync/bb887623). It worked out reasonably well. There are still a few bugs. Here's a [good intro](http://weblogs.asp.net/garrypilkington/starting-with-the-synchronization-framework) to the framework.
This is the significant part of my implementation.

```
 public static bool DirectorySynchronisation(string sourceFiles, string targetFiles)
    {
        Trace.Info("Beginning Directory Sync");
        try
        {
            Trace.Info("... between source location: {0} and targeted location: {1}", sourceFiles, targetFiles);

            //Exclude metadata from sync.
            var fileSyncScopeFilter = new FileSyncScopeFilter();
            fileSyncScopeFilter.FileNameExcludes.Add("metadata.abc");

            // Create file system provider
            var source = new FileSyncProvider(Guid.NewGuid(), sourceFiles, fileSyncScopeFilter, FileSyncOptions.None);
            var target = new FileSyncProvider(Guid.NewGuid(), targetFiles);

            // Ask providers to detect changes
            source.DetectChanges();
            target.DetectChanges();

            // Sync changes
            SyncOrchestrator agent = new SyncOrchestrator
            {
                LocalProvider = source,
                RemoteProvider = target,
                Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.Upload //One way only

            };
            agent.Synchronize();
            Trace.Info("Completed Directory Sync");

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Trace.Info("Exception thrown while syncing files");
            Trace.Exception(exception);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps someone.